# VS code is not able to identify html extension

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

my vs code can't identify which web extension I am using,
It can identify .htm instead of .html extension,
and because of this, it cannot give me a suggestion for an HTML tag.

[image: HMTL Screenshot]
[image: HTM Screenshot]

Comment: ok thanks will check it

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, the problem is that apparently your file association was disconfigured. So, in order to solve it, you need to follow next steps:

In the right bottom of your screen press on the file type name (it's near to the smiley face). I imagine that show something as "Plain text" or something like that.

It should appear a menu. On this menu, choose `Auto detect` option. I think could be work just on that way. Maybe you need to restart your VS Code after that.

If it's not working yet, just choose `Configure File Association for .html` and then choose `HTML`.

And from now on your VS Code be allowed to detect .html files as the correct ones.

Regards!